# Determining whether the homomorphism $\phi$ is surjective.

Tags: ring-theory

**Question.** Suppose that $\phi: \Bbb Q[X, Y]\rightarrow \Bbb Q[T]$ is the homomorphism between polynomial rings defined by $\phi(X)=T^2$ and $\phi(Y)=T^3$. Is $\phi$ surjective?

**Attempt.** Now from what I understand, a function is surjective if the image of the function is the entire codomain, $\Bbb Q[T]$ in this case. Now it seems like I can get all of $\Bbb Q[T]$: $\phi(1)=1$, $\phi(Y/X)=T$, $\phi(X)=T^2$ and so on, so I would say that $\phi$ is surjective.

Am I correct with my answer and reasoning? If not, then what would be the right approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $Y/X$ does *not* belong to the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y].$

Comment: Oh yeah! That is very very true come to think of it. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! :) Can you see why $\phi$ is *not* surjective now? (By the way, you mean $\phi(1)=1$ rather than $\phi(0)=1$).

Comment: Oh yeah, the $0$ and $1$ was just a typo on my part, apologies. But yes, now it seems as though there's no way that the image of $\phi$ can include $T$ anymore so it isn't surjective...I think?

Comment: Yes that's right :)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you ever so much. Please, do feel free to submit your original comment as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rational function $Y/X$ does not belong to the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y].$

As such, you can't say that $\phi(Y/X)=T.$

In fact, there does *not* exist a polynomial $f(X,Y) \in \mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$ such that $f(T^2,T^3)=T.$

Therefore $\phi$ is *not* surjective.